# Current status of the navigation stack tools in ROS2. Where is move_base?

Tags: navigation, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m interested in using the ROS 2 variant of the navigation stack for a simple navigation task, namely, follow a given nav_msgs::Path without caring about obstacle avoidance or anything else.

The repository I'm looking at is: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2

Are the tools needed for this task already ported to ROS 2? After going through bits of the ROS 1 documentation, it seems that `move_base` would be the component to use, but AFAIK, that is not ported to ROS 2. Anything I’m missing? What would you suggest for the application at hand?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323051/current-status-of-the-navigation-stack-tools-in-ros2.-where-is-move_base?/) by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 257 on 2019-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have split move_base up into it's base components in ROS2 and are using behavior trees to drive the components. This provides customizability and extensibility of the stack behavior. However, if you use our nav2_bringup launch files, you don't need to worry about that to get started using the stack.

You can look at the README file in the nav2_bringup folder for an example bringup.

---

Originally posted by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) with karma: 156 on 2019-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2